# Global variable cannot be access in function

Tags: javascript

i've put global variable outside the functions, i have two different function like this

```html
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title></title>


</head>

<body>
  <p>num 1 = <input id="num1" /></p>
  <p>num 2 = <input id="num2" /></p>

  <p><button type="button" onclick="findCalc1()">Calc 1</button>
    <p><button type="button" onclick="findCalc2()">Calc 2</button>

    </p>
    <p>The Result is ...</p>

    <script>
      var b = document.getElementById("num1").value;
      var c = document.getElementById("num2").value;

      function findCalc1() {
        document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = b * c;
      }

      function findCalc2() {
        document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = b / c;
      }
    </script>
    <p id="p1"></p>

    </body
```

but it didn't show any value, what did i do wrong?

Comment: They are accessed fine. It's because they don't have any value when the page first loads which is the only time you grab them, make them local variables inside your function so it gets the updated values.

Comment: aka: `var b = document.getElementById("num1")` and than `...innerHTML = b.value ...`

Comment: The new value was not set during click event. You're actually making a global variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're setting the variables to be equal to the value **on page load**. Once you actually enter something into these fields, the value has already been set.

To remedy this, you simply need to move both of your variable declarations into the two functions:

```js
function findCalc1() {
  b = document.getElementById("num1").value;
  c = document.getElementById("num2").value;
  document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = b * c;
}

function findCalc2() {
  b = document.getElementById("num1").value;
  c = document.getElementById("num2").value;
  document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = b / c;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p>num 1 = <input id="num1" /></p>
  <p>num2 = <input id="num2" /></p>

  <p><button type="button" onclick="findCalc1()">Calc 1</button></p>
  <p><button type="button" onclick="findCalc2()">Calc 2</button></p>

  <p>The Result is ...</p>
  <p id="p1"></p>
</body>
```

Comment: so..it's local variable then? is there anyway to set up global variable?

Comment: Well you'd need to set the variables some time after you actually enter the values. This could be on a button click or even on keyup. Then you'd need to pass those variables into the respective functions to use locally.

Comment: @DesakPutri Why do you think those are local variables? You are changing their value inside those methods, you are not declaring them there, which can be done globally making them global variables. That said it's not really a good idea to have globals that you don't need.

Answer (score 0):

The OP's script actually succeeds in accessing the global variables `b` and `c`. Unfortunately this action occurs as soon as the page loads, well before a user has a chance to provide any input.  The logical result for the multiplication is zero and the division is [NaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN), i.e. the special value for when a math operation fails, such as division by zero in this case.

I revised the code in several ways, including removing variables `b` and `c` from the global space and making them local to a function in order to improve the code's organization.

As soon as the page loads, the button elements are collected and each is  assigned a handler for when a user clicks any of them. The handler, an anonymous function, in turn calls doMathOp(), passing as a parameter a button's id. The user-defined function accesses the two input field values, trimming them of white space characters and assigning them respectively to variables `b` and `c`.

The code calls on a function to validate what the variables hold, checking for empty values or invalid data.  If the callback returns true, then the values are valid and numeric, so the math operation proceeds. If the user clicked the button with an id of "num1", multiplication occurs, otherwise if the other button is clicked, then the function carries out division.

As an aside, note that it is preferable to write HTML without event attributes and instead refer to the events in JavaScript -- it's a cleaner separation of concerns and the following code illustrates this approach:

```js
var d = document;
d.g = d.getElementById;

var num1 = d.g("num1");
var num2 = d.g("num2");
var but1 = d.g("but1");
var but2 = d.g("but2");
var res = d.g("res");

function doValidate() {
  var x = arguments[0];
  var y = arguments[1];

  console.clear();
  // empty value check
  if (x === "" ) {
    console.log("please input a value");
    num1.focus();
  } 
  else
  if (y === "") {
     console.log("please input a value");
     num2.focus()
  }
  else // invalid data check
  if (isNaN(x)) {
      console.log("invalid data: ", x);
      num1.focus();
      num1.select();
  }
  else
  if (isNaN(y)) {
    console.log("invalid data: ", y);
    num2.focus();
    num2.select();
  } else {
    return true;
  }

}

function doMathOp() {
  var b = num1.value.trim();
  var c = num2.value.trim();
  var str = arguments[0];

  if (doValidate(b, c) === true) {
    res.innerHTML = (str === "but1") ? b * c : b / c;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

window.onload = function() {
  var buts = d.getElementsByTagName("button");
  for (let i = 0, max = buts.length; i < max; i++) {
    buts[i].onclick = function() {
      doMathOp(this.id);
    };
  }
};
```

```css
button {
  background: #eeeee;
  width: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}

#label {
  line-height: 0.2;
}

#res {
  background: #eff;
  width: 250px;
  border: 2px dotted #f0f;
}
```

```html
<p>#1 = <input id="num1" /></p>
<p>#2 = <input id="num2" /></p>
<button id="but1" type="button">Multiply</button><br>
<button id="but2" type="button">Divide</button>
<p id="label">Result:</p>
<p id="res"> </p>
```